# Query in volterra kernel

Tags: image-processing, kernel, svm

I need code for volterra kernel. I don't know how to define and implement the volterra kernel. I need to fuse this kernel in support vector machine (SVM) for image retrieval.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Given the training data set, use the code mentioned above to train the Volterra kernels. Once the Volterra kernel (v) have been obtained compute kernel matrix K where the ith row and jth column of the matrix is given by CONVOLUTION(d_i-d_j,v). Use this Matrix K with SVM. Note that the kernel is Volterra Kernel (v) is different than the "kernel" (K) used in SVM.